# substr() is not working as expected

Tags: php, date, substring

I am just trying to extract the date's `year`, `month` and `day` separately so that I can use it as per my wish.

I stored the current date in `$today` and used `substr()` to extract the strings from it. But I am getting some strange behaviour from what I am doing.

My current code:

```
$today = date("Y/m/d");

$_year = substr($today, 0,4);
$_month = substr($today, 5,7);
$_day = substr($today, 8, 10);

echo $_year . " " . $_month;
```

The `$_year` works correctly as expected but the problem arises from `$_month`, no matter what position I start my `substr()` the month and day gets paired up with each other.

Can anyone help me solve this issue? It's driving me crazy.

Comment: Whats the output did you get?

Comment: $_month = substr($today, 5,7); should be $_month = substr($today, 5,2); you want 2 chars from position 5, not 7

Comment: @Grumpy javascript is the culprit here! ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should have a look at `substr` reference: http://php.net/manual/it/function.substr.php

That function accepts 3 parameters: `$length` is the length of the string you want to cut starting from `$start`

```
string substr ( string $string , int $start [, int $length ] )
```

In your case, this will work properly:

```
$today = date("Y/m/d");
$_year = substr($today, 0,4);
$_month = substr($today, 5,2);
$_day = substr($today, 8, 2);
echo $_year." ".$_month;
```

Comment: I was learning JavaScript before working on PHP so I did this silly mistake! Thanks mate

Answer (score 5):

This should work for you:

Just [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) your date by a slash and then use a [`list()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.list.php) to assign the variables.

```
list($year, $month, $day) = explode("/", $today);
```

Answer (score 5):

Just use:

```
echo date("Y m");
```

If you want to have every part of the date in an individual variable, I highly encourage you to use the [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class:

```
$dt = new DateTime();
$year = $dt->format('Y');
$month = $dt->format('m');
$day = $dt->format('d');

echo $dt->format('Y m');
```

Comment: Did you had to put the dots there only because of the character limit ?!

Comment: For what do you think there is a character limit? Because of unicorns (Just kidding  :)? (^ See now you have even something better for OP.)

Comment: well that's bit more complex for a learner ...anyway appreciate it!

Comment: @DisortedCasanøva I would recommend you to keep an eye on the `DateTime` class if you have to do more stuff with dates this will get very useful!

Comment: @DisortedCasanøva I don't get what do you think is more complex with that. It is actually a lot simpler than your attempt! (Less function calls, less logic). Note that simplicity is one of the design goals of the `DateTime` API.

Comment: :p don't know I feel it easy this way ..but thank you brother in future I will look into the ways you said!

Answer (score 1):

```
$today = date("Y/m/d");
$_year = substr($today, 0,4);
$_month = substr($today, 5,7);
$_day = substr($today, 8, 10);
echo $_year." ".$_month;
```

should be

```
$today = date("Y/m/d");
$_year = substr($today, 0,4);
$_month = substr($today, 5,2);
$_day = substr($today, 8, 2);
echo $_year." ".$_month;
```

Answer (score 1):

`substr()` doesn't work asyou think

You're thinking of :
`string substr ( string $string , int $start , int $end )`

But it is :
`string substr ( string $string , int $start , [int $length)`

So use `substr($today,5,2)` for month and `substr($today,7,2)` for day

Comment: well I am coming from JavaScript so I find it culprit! Thanks man!

Comment: No problem, I know that feel :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use it as

```
$today = date("Y/m/d");
$today = explode("/", $today);
$year = $today[0];
$month = $today[1]; 
$day = $today[2];
echo $year . ' ' . $month .' '. $day; // 2015 05 05
```